# How to execute network request when leaving Fragment?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

How to conveniently perform a network request when exiting one Fragment using Coroutines and ViewModel?

The workflow is: user enters a Fragment A containing list of Boxes' names. He picks one and is navigated to Fragment B where he can scan barcodes, which are added into chosen Box (in memory). When scanned all required barcodes he clicks Back button and in this moment mentioned Box with  barcodes should be sent to server (serialized into JSON of course).

ViewModelScope of course is not a solution since Fragment's B ViewModel is cleared. I tried using WorkManager, but I can't figure out how to do it conveniently - it requires passing a Context reference to ViewModel (which I would like avoid in order to make ViewModel clean from Android's platform references and make unit tests simple) and passing a Box using Data object.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the host Activity `ViewModel` from the the Fragment for shared actions. So in your case, make the network request from the host Activity `ViewModel`. So the network request will continue executing while you navigate form Fragment A to B, and the data will be preserved on the Activity ViewModel, hence you can access the value from any Fragment hosted by the same Activity.

You can get the shared `ViewModel` by the following method

```
activity?.let {
sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
}
```

---

### Bonus Point

Even though the OP does not want to use ViewModel scoped to the Graph , it is considered as more perfect approach. Here is how you can get a ViewModel specific to a Graph

[image: graph scoped viewModel example image]

```
val viewModel: CheckoutViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.checkout_graph)
```

Comment: That was one of solutions I considered, but it also seems a little bit clanky since this is a single Activity app. How would You pass the Box object between these two ViewModels?

Comment: Fragment has access to its own ViewModel and Activity ViewModel, so Fragment A can simply pass the box object into the Activity ViewModel, then observe the value from Fragment B